# Can't get request form from HTML form

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have a form in which I have several inputs, when I submit the form to process the information, when I try to read them I can't.

This is the form:

```
<form id="form1" action="page.aspx" method="get">
      <input type="text" name="idP" id="idP" value="123456789" />
...
        </form>
```

Then when I send it to "page.aspx" The url show the data:

```
localhost/page?idP=123456789
```

But when I try to read them from code as:

```
string[] keys = Request.Form.AllKeys;
            for (int i = 0; i < keys.Length; i++)
            {
                Response.Write(keys[i] + ": " + Request.Form[keys[i]] + "<br>");
            }
```

It doesn't print anything, and AllKeys shows as 0 values, I tried with "Post" method as well but nothing.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You can get the value of `idP` with `Request.QueryString`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike POST and PUT, GET requests don't have a body<sup>1</sup>, so form values must be sent via the query string.  You can see this in your URI: `localhost/page?idP=123456789`.

So, you'll need to use something like:

```
var idP = Request.QueryString["idP"];
```

`Request.Form` pulls values from the request *body*.  From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.form(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The Form property is populated when the HTTP request Content-Type value is either "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" or "multipart/form-data".

If you look at the your request headers, you'll see that Content-Type a) is missing entirely, or b) isn't either of those.  So, using it here isn't appropriate.

<sup>1</sup>: Technically, GET requests can have a body, but per the HTTP specification, servers should ignore it.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/983458/47589) for more information.